# Slide content based on the speed of the mouse

Tags: javascript

I have this carousel type item:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/xOpzqK?editors=1111

What I am trying to do now, is change it's behaviour. I would like the drag to know the speed of the mouse and try to mimic the scroll to that speed. When I let go of the mouse I want the slider to continue sliding but slow down over a period of time.
My first step was trying to get the actual speed of the mouse, so I did this:

```
var eventHandler = function (e) {

    var event = _options.event;
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var touches = event.touches = e.originalEvent !== undefined ? e.originalEvent.touches : null;
            
    if (e.type === 'mousedown') {

        // Assign the timer to our event
        event.timer = $timeout(function () {

            // If we have not already enabled the event
            if (!event.enabled) {

                // Set our startX and the time
                event.startX = touches ? touches[0].pageX : e.clientX;
                event.timestamp = timestamp;

                //console.log(event);

                // Enable our drag
                event.enabled = true;
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    if (e.type === 'mousemove' && event.enabled) {

        // Get our old position
        var x = event.currentX;

        //console.log(timestamp);
        //console.log(event.timestamp);
        //console.log('calc', timestamp - event.timestamp);
                
        // Update our current position and speed
        event.currentX = touches ? touches[0].pageX : e.clientX;
        event.distance = event.currentX - (x || event.startX);
        event.time = timestamp - event.timestamp;
        event.timestamp = timestamp;
        event.speed = (event.distance / event.time) * $window.innerWidth;

        //console.log('distance', event.distance);
        //console.log('time in seconds', event.time);
        //console.log('speed', event.speed);
        //console.log('------');

        // Work out our offset
        var offset = event.currentX / $window.innerWidth;

        console.log(offset);

        // If we have not started
        if (!event.started) {

            // Set our initial start position
            event.xOffset = offset;

            // Initial our position
            event.oldX = event.pageX;

            // Set to started
            event.started = true;
        }

        // Udpate our position
        event.pageX = (offset - event.xOffset) + event.oldX;

        // Set our new offset
        event.xOffset = offset;

        // Update our element
        _updateDragElement(_options.element, event);

        // Update our old position
        event.oldX = event.pageX;
    }

    if (['mouseup', 'mouseout'].indexOf(e.type) > -1) {

        // Clear our timer
        $timeout.cancel(event.timer);

        //console.log(event);

        // If our data is set
        if (event.enabled) {

            // Unset it
            event.enabled = false;
        }

        // Stop the drag
        event.start = false;
    }
}
```

I will break this down into the events

### Mouse down

As you can see from the **eventHandler** when the **mousedown** event is triggered, a start position **startX** is recorded along with the current **timestamp**.

### Mouse move

When the **mousemove** event is triggered I check to see if we are already moving by getting the value in **currentX**. I then set **currentX**, the **distance** travelled (current position minus the last position OR the start position if there is no current position.) Then I work out the **time** and record the current **timestamp** and finally I work out the **speed**.
I then get the **xOffset** by dividing **currentX** by the width of the window.
If the animation has not started I set the **xOffset** and set the **oldX** to the current **pageX** and then I start the animation.
The **pageX** is worked out by **xOffset** minus the current **xOffset** plus the **oldX**, then I update the new **xOffset**.
Then I update the element with the new **transform** and finally set my **oldX** to the current **pageX**.

### Mouse up

For this I just disable and stop the animation.

### Problem

The problem I have is that the speed is very low, so the animation doesn't work well.
I decided to multiple the speed by the window width but the animation is no better because it just jerks around.
I think I am doing my calculations incorrectly so I was hoping someone could take a look and give me some advice.

Comment: you not need animation while dragging, instead just calculate final point and  current cursor speed, from this calculate animation time and enable animation **after mouseup** , but anyway all such effects will be uggly and unexpected, if you going to use it in mobile - just use native scroll

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codepen, your calculation looks fine. Only transition property seems to be missing for the scrolling element, try giving transition property to `.pk-slider-base` class.

```
.pk-slider .pk-slider-base {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

You can also try adding transition using Javascript in your `updateView()`.

Please see below:

```
function updateView() {
  "use strict";
  finalX = pageX * mySpeed;
  console.log('X', pageX);
  console.log('speed', mySpeed);
  yourTrans = 'translateX(' + finalX + 'px)';
  yourElement.style.transform = yourTrans;
  /*Adding transition*/
  yourElement.style.WebkitTransition = "all 2s";
  yourElement.style.transition = "all 2s";
}
```